# My custom Android toast shows no text

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, styling, android-toast

wise people!

This is my first question here. I'm stuck with a problem that seemed pretty simple to solve to me. I am not able to show a custom Toast message in my Android app.

There are two custom layouts I've created

1. my_toast.xml - layout file

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/text"
    android:background="@color/yumist_red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dp" 
    android:paddingRight="20dp" 
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text = "ToastText"
    android:gravity = "center"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

2. my_toast_up.xml

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/chat_arrow" 
        android:rotation="180"
        />
    
    <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/text"
    android:background="@color/yumist_red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dp" 
    android:paddingRight="20dp" 
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text = "ToastText"
    android:gravity = "center"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

The only difference in the two is an imageview containing an arrow image. I'm trying to create text-bubble-style Toast.

I am well able to show and use the first one in my app. But, when I use the second layout with the image, all I see is the Image and an empty TextView of the ImageView's width and standard height. I've tried a lot of posts and existing questions online, but I cannot find a solution to this.

Any help?

[java code for showing Toasts]

```js
 public static void showToast(String message, int type)
 { //'message' is the text to display, 'type' determines which of the three toasts is shown
      
      /*
      * There are three fixed toasts:
      * 1. One pointing upwards (with an angle) and placed near the top. (upperNotification)
      * 2. Placed in the default position, to show general messages. (no issues with this | mToast)
      * 3. Placed to point at bar at the bottom. (lowerNotification)
      */
      
      
  TextView textView = null ;            //this will refer to the message TextView 
                                              //corresponding to the toast selected
  Toast toast = null;                   //to refer to the toast to display
  switch(type)
  {
  case MyToast.ARROW_DOWN:textView = lowerToastText; toast = lowerNotification; break;

  case MyToast.ARROW_UP:textView = upperToastText; toast= upperNotification; break;

  case MyToast.ARROW_NONE:textView = toastText; toast = mToast; break;
  }
  if(textView != null && toast != null)
  {
   
   System.out.println(message);
   textView.setText(message);
   toast.show();
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("NULL!");
  }
 }

//Below is the code I used to init these.

 public static void setUpToast(Activity activity, LayoutInflater inflater)
 {
  mToast = new Toast(activity);
  upperNotification = new Toast(activity);
  lowerNotification = new Toast(activity);
  
  View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_toast, null);
  toastText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
  mToast.setView(layout);
  mToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  
  layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_toast_up, null);
  upperToastText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
  upperNotification.setView(layout);
  upperNotification.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP, 0, Dish.dpToPx(96, activity));
  upperNotification.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  
  layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_toast_down, null);
  lowerToastText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
  lowerNotification.setView(layout);
  lowerNotification.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, Dish.dpToPx(48, activity));
  lowerNotification.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  
 }
```

Comment: Please share the code you are using to show the toast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a fix by trial-and-error myself.

In my layout, I had kept my TextViews' width to match its parent. That was causing it to shrink down the ImageView's width for some reason.

I changed it to *WRAP_CONTENT* and of the parent view to MATCH_PARENT and it fixed my problem.

I am, however, still curious if there's a way to show the text with the parent's width.

Comment: Change the parent layout from Linear layout to Relative layout

Comment: Thanks @3amoura ! I'll try to implement this. (Y)